# Fetching nested API data to reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django

I am encountering a blank display whilst fetching the API data provided below. How can I modify my code to display this nested data in React

```
[
    {
        "pk_id": "HTR4q",
        "name": " Contagious Bovine Pleuropneumonia(CBPP)",
        "species": "cattle",
        "language": "en-uk",
        "translations": {
            "en-uk": {
                "subcategory": "Diseases with respiratory/breathing signs",
                "subcategory_desc": "Diseases described in this section are those that have respiratory/breathing signs as the main indication of illness. These include Contagious Bovine Pleuropneumonia and East Coast fever.",
                "name": "Contagious Bovine Pleuropneumonia (CBPP)",
                "local_names": "Somali Berfur, Sambab\r\nBorana Sombes\r\nRendille Argab Looyo\r\nSamburu Lkipei, Loonkishu\r\nTurkana Loukoi Angaatuk\r\nGabra Sombes",
                "other_livestock_affected": "It affects cattle only.",
                "transmission": "Susceptible cattle become infected by inhalation of droplets from an affected animal. Urine droplets from a sick animal can also transmit the disease. Transmission can occur even if a healthy animal is between 20 to 200 metres away from an infected one.",
                "distribution": "",
                "number_affected": "In unexposed populations, up to 100% are affected. In areas where the disease is common, 10–60% of the animals are affected.",
                "death_rate": "In unexposed populations, the disease can kill more than 50% of the animals. In areas where the disease is common, less than 10% of the– animals die from the disease.",
                "predisposing_factors": "Occurs in all seasons\r\nLivestock movement – mixing of herds at watering points and on grazing fields\r\nPresence of susceptible animals\r\nSub clinical or carrier animals in the herd",
                "key_signs": "Rocking body back and forth while breathing, with some grunting—breathing is shallow and rapid \r\nDry cough upon exercise\r\nStanding with arched back, elbows out and head and neck extended\r\nAnimal faces the wind with its nostrils wide open (dilated)",
                "dead_animal_signs": "",
                "other_signs": "Animal seeks shade\r\nNasal discharge \r\nDepression\r\nLags behind as the herd moves\r\nEmaciation \r\nTearing",
                "prevention": "Separate infected animal \r\nIsolate affected herds \r\nControlled livestock movement\r\nBiannual vaccination\r\nMake sure introduced animals into your herd are healthy—seek veterinary advice",
                "human_prevention": "",
                "human_management": "",
                "zoonotic_potential": null
            }]
```

This is my Jsx code used to Fetch and mapped over the data but the contents under the various translations e.g. en-uk could not be displayed. it would be great if anybody could help me out with what I am trying to solve. Thank you so much in advance.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [diseaseData, setDiseaseData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/disease/");
      const data = await response.json();
      setDiseaseData(data);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
  };

 

  const getTranslation = (langCode) => {
    if (diseaseData && diseaseData.translations) {
      return diseaseData.translations[langCode] || null;
    }
    return null;
  };

  console.log("Rendering"); // Debugging console log
  console.log("diseaseData:", diseaseData);
  console.log(
    "translations keys:",
    diseaseData && Object.keys(diseaseData.translations || {})
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {diseaseData &&
        diseaseData.translations &&
        Object.keys(diseaseData.translations).map((langCode) => {
          const translation = getTranslation(langCode);
          if (!translation) {
            return null; // Skip if translation is not available
          }
          return (
            <div key={langCode}>
              <h2>{translation("en-uk").name}</h2>
              <p>{translation.subcategory}</p>
              <p>{translation.subcategory_desc}</p>
              {/* Display other data properties for each translation */}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Could you provide the result of `console.log("diseaseData:", diseaseData);` please ?

Comment: Hi Tam, this is the data 
```
language: "en-uk"
pk_id: "NWQ8z"
species: "cattle"
translations: en-uk: 
{subcategory: 'Diseases with respiratory/breathing signs', subcategory_desc: 'Diseases described in this section are those that …ious Bovine Pleuropneumonia and East Coast fever.', name: 'Contagious Bovine Pleuropneumonia (CBPP)', local_names: 'Somali Berfur, Sambab\r\nBorana Sombes\r\nRendille Arg… Loonkishu\r\nTurkana Loukoi Angaatuk\r\nGabra Sombes', other_livestock_affected: 'It affects cattle only.', …}
```
It is the JSON from the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've had time to check out the issue. Here's your problem :
When you're trying to access your data in the `return` call, you're trying to map over the keys of `diseaseData.translations`, then you're referencing the `getTranslation` method, but this method doesn't keep track of your state (`diseaseData`). After that, when iterating over your translations, you're using `{translation("en-uk").name}`, which roughly translates to "call the `translation` method with `"en-uk"` as a parameter and return the `name` field of the result you get.

Here's how to fix this :

```
const Home = () => {
  const [diseaseData, setDiseaseData] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/disease/")
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((result) => { setDiseaseData(result); })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]); // You missed a dependency here
  
  const getTranslation = useCallback((langCode) => { 
    return diseaseData?.translations?.[langCode] || null;
  }, [diseaseData?.translations]); // This dependency array ensures the `getTranslation` method keeps track of the state.

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(diseaseData?.translations ?? {})?.map((langCode) => {
        const translation = getTranslation(langCode);
        if (!translation) {
          return null;
        }
        return (
          <div key={langCode}>
            <h2>{translation.name}</h2>
            <p>{translation.subcategory}</p>
            // ...
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
};
```

On a side note, there are some performance issues that may arise later on (especially the way you're referencing `getTranslation` in the return's `map`, but I didn't touch on that as you're likely just starting off in your project and I didn't want to overwhelm you with too much information, so I only provided a fix for the issue you were facing. Feel free to ask if you're interested !

Comment: Hi Tam, thanks for the fix, it's still not rendering fully but my thinking is that the null handling in the rendering could be the culprit. Sure I would like to optimize the code further to cater for performance related issues.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Could you please clarify what you mean by your content "not rendering **fully**" ?
As for the possible optimisations, I would need more details regarding your use cases (for instance, will you display multiple languages at the same time ?)

Comment: I appreciate it Tam, for the rendering part, I just solved that. Yes, the use case will be displaying multiple languages